# Read Int value from bytea column in Postgres

Tags: xml, postgresql, xpath

I need to get an int value from bytea column named attributes (Stores XML) in Postgres. Here is a sample XML of what attributes column could contain:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE properties SYSTEM "http://java.sun.com/dtd/properties.dtd">
<properties>
<entry key="product.name">DISC.22%</entry>
</properties>
```

I need to get 22 Int value (DISC.22%). Is there a way to do this in Postgres?

Comment: Why not to store XML as ... `XML` type?

Comment: Or just simple plain `text`. Why binary `bytea` for text data?

Answer (score 2):

You can try to convert your `bytea` to actual text with `convert_from(string bytea, src_encoding name)`.

Then cast `text` to `XML` and use `xpath` to get your value.

Or just regexp the `text`.

This links might be helpfull: [`one`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-string.html), [`two`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-xml.html), [`three`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html).